# Using Pagination for Custom Post Type and keeps returning 404

Tags: custom-post-types, php, pagination, paginate-links

I'm able to return the correct page numbers (1 post per page) but the paginated links keep returning a 404 page. Here's the function I'm calling for the pagination:

```
//Pagination for Custom Taxonomy Terms
function custom_page_navi( $totalpages, $page, $end_size, $mid_size )
{
    $bignum = 999999999;

    if ( $totalpages <= 1 || $page > $totalpages ) return;

        //NOTE: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links
    return paginate_links( array(
        'total'         => $totalpages,
        'prev_next'     => false,
        'type'          => 'list',
        'show_all'      => false,
        'end_size'      => $end_size,
        'mid_size'      => $mid_size
    ) );

}
```

Here is code I'm using for within my taxonomy-page-name.php file:

```
      <?php

$this_page_taxonomy = $wp_query->get_queried_object(); //getting this page terms
$current_slug       = $this_page_taxonomy->slug; //current slug
$time               = current_time('timestamp'); //current time
$go_cpt             = 'name'; //taxonony  name
$number             = 1; // number of terms to display per page


// Setup for pagination:
$page       = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$offset     = ($page > 0) ? $number * ($page - 1) : 1;
$totalposts = $this_page_taxonomy->count;
$totalpages = ceil($totalposts / $number);

$go_args = array(
    'post_type' => $go_cpt,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key' => 'go_series_date',
    'meta_value' => $time,
    'meta_compare' => '>=',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'exclude' => array(),
    'exclude_tree' => array(),
    'include' => array(),
    'posts_per_page' => $number,
    'fields' => 'all',
    'slug' => '',
    'parent' => '',
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'child_of' => 0,
    'get' => '',
    'name__like' => '',
    'pad_counts' => false,
    'offset' => $offset,
    'search' => '',
    'cache_domain' => 'core',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'go_series',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $current_slug
        )
    )
);



$go_recent_posts = new WP_Query($go_args);

if ($go_recent_posts->have_posts()):
    while ($go_recent_posts->have_posts()):
        $go_recent_posts->the_post();

        printf('<nav class="recent-series__pagination">%s</nav>', custom_page_navi($totalpages, $page, 3, 0));
    endwhile;
endif;

?>
```

Is it potentially a rewrite problem?? Not sure what's going on here...Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, you're throwing away the default query for the page (after it hits the DB and sets up the globals) with your custom query. The pagination is referring to the default query for the template, which is defined in Settings > Reading, plus you're hitting the DB twice for the same thing, which is hideously inefficient.

If you want to change the options of the main query for a template you should hook into `pre_get_posts` and modify the default query before it's sent to the DB, like so:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse276456_custom_tax_query');

function wpse276456_custom_tax_query($query) {
  if(is_tax('page-name') {
     $query->set('posts_per_page', 1);
     // Add more calls to $query->set as necessary
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! Rather than using the default query, can I not use my custom query for pagination though?

Comment: Adding a custom query should only be used for supplementary Loops on the same page, if you want to alter what's displayed for the main query hooking to `pre_get_posts` and altering it is the correct method.

Comment: That was it! Thanks!! Post as an answer when you get a momentt

Comment: It already is...